# How to talk with a service in android

Tags: android

I have an activity that start a foreground service.
The service start a class (recwav) that record voice from mic.
From the activity I need to access to the recwav class tonget maxamplitude of audio record.

What is correct way?

Using messenger object or brodcast ?
Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason to record voice specifically in a service? A service is not a thread, remember. For nonblocking background processing, use a thread (or AsyncTask) instead.

Comment: Seva, the reason is to make sure the recording will not be stopped from Android, so Foreground service must guarantee the continue recording for long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an example of a local service. You can bind your Activity to the service and your Activity class will then be able to call any public methods that you expose on that Service class:

> One of the most common uses of a Service is as a secondary component
>   running alongside other parts of an application, in the same process
>   as the rest of the components. All components of an .apk run in the
>   same process unless explicitly stated otherwise, so this is a typical
>   situation.
>
> When used in this way, by assuming the components are in the same
>   process, you can greatly simplify the interaction between them:
>   clients of the service can simply cast the IBinder they receive from
>   it to a concrete class published by the service.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Comment: twaddington, the local service sample you propose do not say you can call public methods but you can send msg and receive callback, I am wrong?

Comment: That's incorrect. Using the LocalService binder example will give you an instance of the service that you can invoke methods on directly just like any regular object.